# Create a colour histogram from an image file

Tags: nim-lang

I'd like to use Nim to check the results of my Puppeteer test run executions.
Part of the end result is a screenshot. That screenshot should contain a certain amount of active colours. An active colour being orange, blue, red, or green. They indicate activity is present in the incoming data. Black, grey, and white need to be excluded, they only represent static data.

I haven't found a solution I can use yet.

```
import stb_image/read as stbi

var
  w, h , c:int
  data: seq[uint8]
  cBin: array[256,int] #colour range was 0->255 afaict
data = stbi.load("screenshot.png",w,h,c,stbi.Default)
for d in data:
  cBin[(int)d] = cBin[(int)d] + 1
echo cBin
```

Now I have a uint array, which I can see I can use to construct a histogram of the values, but I don't know how to map these to something like RGB values. Pointers anyone?

Is there a better package which has this automagically, I didn't spot one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stbi.load()` will return a sequence of interleaved uint8 color components. The number of interleaved components is determined either by `c` (i.e. `channels_in_file`) or `desired_channels` when it is non-zero.

For example, when `channels_in_file == stbi.RGB and desired_channels == stbi.Default` there are 3 interleaved components of red, green, and blue.

```
[
# r    g    b
  255, 0,   0,   # Pixel 1
  0,   255, 0,   # Pixel 2
  0,   0,   255, # Pixel 3
]
```

You can process the above like:

```
import colors
for i in countUp(0, data.len - 3, step = stbi.RGB):
  let
    r = data[i + 0]
    g = data[i + 1]
    b = data[i + 2]
    pixelColor = colors.rgb(r, g, b)
  echo pixelColor
```

You can read more on this within comments for the stb_image.h.

Comment: Thanks, stbi_image was the only package that I could get to work out of the box on Windows. I didn't find any documentation for how it was supposed to work though - this is exactly what I was missing.